# Erro em CRUD com .NET MVC

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc

Estou tentando recuperar alguns dados do meu banco, mas está dando o seguinte erro

> Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

[image: Erro que aparece quando tento recuperar]

Não tenho a mínima ideia do que está acontecendo.

Classe Usuario

```
public class Usuario
{
    [Key]
    public int UsuarioId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Senha { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Sobrenome { get; set; }
    public float Latitude { get; set; }
    public float Longitude { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public bool Confirmado { get; set; }
    public string Apelido { get; set; }
    public string Imagem { get; set; }
    public bool Privado { get; set; }
    public string ImagemCapa { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataNascimento { get; set; }
    public int Sexo { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataExpiracaoToken { get; set; }
    public int EstiloId { get; set; }
    public Estilo Estilo { get; set; }
```

Classe Estilo

```
public class Estilo
{
    [Key]
    public int EstiloId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Local { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }
```

Classe de configuração do estilo para o code-first

```
public EstiloConfig()
    {
        HasKey(a => a.EstiloId);

        HasMany(a => a.Usuarios).WithRequired(a => a.Estilo).HasForeignKey(a => a.EstiloId);

        Property(a => a.Nome).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(45);
        Property(a => a.Local).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(100);
    }
```

Comment: Pode editar sua pergunta e colocar a declaração do *Model*? É um problema de índice.

Comment: isso ai @CiganoMorrisonMendez ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não use `[Index]` pra chaves primárias. Não funciona.

Modifique para o seguinte:

```
public class Estilo 
{
    [Key]
    public int EstiloId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Local { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }
}
```

---

**EDIT**

[Esta resposta aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24990287/1314276) enuncia que você deve forçar a configuração do seu contexto da seguinte forma:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public class MeuContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext()
        : base()
    {
        this.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
    }

    static MyContext()
    {
            DbConfiguration.SetConfiguration(new MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration());
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Muito possivelmente a configuração do projeto não está ok. Seria legal você revisar seu `web.config` se baseando [nas várias perguntas que já foram feitas sobre isso aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+%5Bentity-framework%5D+web.config).

Comment: Vou mudar, e ver o que acontece..

Comment: Continuou dando o mesmo erro..

Comment: @FrankDantas Atualize sua pergunta com `Usuario` também, por favor. Não use imagens na pergunta. Cole o código e use o guia de formatação.

Comment: @FrankDantas Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Mesmo mudando para `[Key]` ainda gerou a index no banco, removi o index com sql mesmo, mas ainda o erro continua..

Comment: @FrankDantas Atualizei a resposta mais uma vez.

Comment: Opa.. Agora sim, ficou certinho, digo, não está mais dando o erro, porém não esta retornando nada ainda, mesmo tendo dados no banco.. Mas aí ja é assunto para outro tópico, vou dar mais uma olhada aqui.  o/